# Transfer from regular savings to NRO account

Tags: india, non-resident

I have a regular savings account in India and a NRE/NRO account as well with a different bank. I just haven't gotten around converting my regular savings to NRE/NRO. Can I move my funds from regular savings to NRO?

Comment: My experience was that Bank A insisted on that I change the regular savings account to a NRO account first. They would not close the account or allow any withdrawals until the conversion was done. After that, I could close the account and take the proceeds as a cheque payable to me but they demanded to know the details of the NRO account in Bank B into which the check was to be deposited before issuing the cheque.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer from Savings account into NRE is not possible.

Transfer into NRO may be possible in certain cases and would require some paperwork. Please consult the Bank where you hold the account to advise you the details.